# Dividing div height over child elements

Tags: html, css

I am doing some html and css.

I'm currently having a problem with a div that contains fieldsets.
I want my fieldsets to fill the entire div's height. So if my div is 300px high, both fieldsets should take 150px. I don't want my div to have a fixed height. I also don't want to work with position: absolute.

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/131/)

As you can see there is an empty space at the end of the div. I want the fieldsets to take up all that empty space.

This is my code:

```
<div id="thediv">
    <legend>somefieldset</legend>
    <fieldset id="one">
        <input type="text" value="input1">
        <input type="text" value="input2">
    </fieldset>
    <legend>somefieldset2</legend>
    <fieldset id="two">
        <input type="text" value="input3">
    </fieldset> 
</div>

#thediv{
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px black solid; 
    width: 50%;
}

#one,#two{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I hope my question is clear. If it isn't, leave a comment.

Comment: Try using min-height of 150px as min-height of your div is 300px. http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pynhA/132/

Comment: Please try this http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/135/ just using heigth: 150px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `display: flex`? It is supported in Chrome, Firefox and IE10+ with vendor prefixes and a slightly different syntax in IE10.

Read more about how to use `display: flex` here: [MDN Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/137/)**

```
#thediv{
    min-height:300px;
    border:1px black solid; 
    width:50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#one,#two{
    flex: 1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you don't want to use absolute and relative positioning but just look at this fiddle first.

http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/138/

This uses relative and absolute positioning. The trick to making it responsive is adding a padding-bottom to the overall container:

```
#thediv {
    border:1px black solid;
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
```

This trick is incredibly useful when trying to maintain aspect ratios for videos or divs with background images.